# Locate no Delphi

Tags: delphi

Tenho um `DataSet` que retorna várias linhas e em uma das colunas tenho a `Situação` do registro que pode ser: aberto, fechado, em conferência, conferido, finalizado...

Preciso verificar se existe alguma situação que não seja `conferido`, tentei o `Locate` direto com o conferido, mas da forma que fiz não vai dar certo.

Outra possibilidade seria fazer um `Locate` para cada uma das situações a se aplicar a restrição, mas gostaria de algo melhor que fazer vários `IFs`.

```
if not dmContratoEmpresarial.cdsContratoEmpresarialContratos.Locate('SITUACAO', 'CONFERIDO', []) then
    fMensagem.Adicionar('Os contratos não foram todos conferidos');
```

Comment: Por que você usa uma query e faz um select? Seleciona todos os registros daqueles contratos que tenha situação diferente de conferido. Se retornar algum você sabe que tem contratos não conferidos. Além de o select ser bem mais rápido que o Locate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O método `Locate` posiciona o cursor no primeiro registro cuja coluna especificada seja **igual** ou (**parcialmente igual**) ao valor especificado, retornando *false* caso não encontre registro nestas condições.

De modo que este método de busca parece não ser adequado para a sua necessidade.

Você pode usar então a propriedade `Filter`, mais ou menos assim:

```
cdsContratoEmpresarialContratos.Filter := 'SITUACAO <> ''CONFERIDO'''`;
cdsContratoEmpresarialContratos.Filtered := True;
```

Pronto. Agora o `dataset` contém apenas os registros que não satisfaçam a condição, ou seja, os "contratos que não foram conferidos".

Você pode contar os registros no `dataset` (propriedade `RowCount` se for um `clientdataset`, e pelo nome do componente parece que é), mostrando a mensagem de que há contratos não conferidos caso haja mais de um registro, ou pode ainda **mostrar** para o usuário os contratos não conferidos (que são todos os reigistros ainda presentes no `dataset`).

Para desabilitar o filtro, basta setar a propriedade `Filtered` novamente para *false*:

```
cdsContratoEmpresarialContratos.Filtered := False;
```